# Disable rainbow variables in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I accidentally enabled rainbow variables in PhpStorm and it looks absolutely horrible. It sounds kinda silly but I just cant find the settings to disable them.

[image]

I have looked up the extension and followed the steps to uninstall but I haven't found anything related to rainbow variables https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17748-rainbow-variable

[image]

I also uninstalled Rainbow Brackets and everything else relating to styling code or variables from the plugins page

[image]

And yes I restarted the IDE after those changes with no success. I'm currently on the version 2022.2.3 of PhpStorm.

Comment: **1)** On Plugins screen -- use `/downloaded` to see all custom (not bundled by default) plugins (that's in case if you have the plugin still there just not showing up there when searching for whatever reason) **2)** `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | Language Defaults | Semantic highlighting` -- make sure it is disabled there. **3)** Please note that [Rainbow Brackets plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10080-rainbow-brackets) turns the above option ON automatically and prevents disabling it (on IDE restart). It should be fixed in latest versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, point two solved it. Semantic highlighting apparently stays activated even after uninstalling the plugin.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have disabled that Rainbow Variables plugin and still seeing the functionality then it might be PhpStorm's Semantic Highlighting in action.

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | Language Defaults | Semantic highlighting` and make sure it is disabled there.

[image]

---

**Please note** that [Rainbow Brackets plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10080-rainbow-brackets) turns the above option ON automatically and prevents disabling it (on IDE restart). This should be fixed in latest plugin versions:

- 2022.3.3 [Fix #2541: [Rainbow variables] Ask to enable rainbow variables before turn it on](https://github.com/izhangzhihao/intellij-rainbow-brackets/issues/2541)
- 2022.3.4 [Fix #2551: [Rainbow variables] rainbow variable does not take effect after IDEA is restarted](https://github.com/izhangzhihao/intellij-rainbow-brackets/issues/2551)

Comment: Thank you for this. Rainbow Brackets turned it on and nothing I could find would turn it off!  This was using CLion, so I assume this setting is across the intellij platform.

Answer (score 0):

For PhpStorm 2022.3, it is here we can disable rainbow variables (even for .json file, where each line has a diffent color).

[image: Disable "raibow" variables]

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem in IntelliJ. However, there're checkboxes in the  IntelliJ settings -> Rainbow Brackets(yes, it has an independent setting bar). If PS has the same form of settings, you may uncheck the 'rainbow variable' box. [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLzKM.jpg)